# Ignore keyword in Listings

Tags: listings

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[keywordstyle = \textbf, language = SQL, deletekeywords = {time}]
create table Event (id integer primary key, time date);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This prints ‘time’ in boldface, using the `listings` package revision 15878 (1.4), TeX Live 2012. How can I make Listings ignore the ‘time’ keyword?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it is defined as an *end* keyword and can be deleted only with the (deprecated) `deletendkeywords`. Looks like a bug to me. However, you have to use the uppercase version of the keyword as it is defined in the language file.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[keywordstyle=\textbf, language=SQL, deletendkeywords={TIME}]
create table Event (id integer primary key, time date);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was also true of the Python keyword `filter`; I had to use `deletendkeywords={filter}`.

Comment: Ditto for Python keyword `list`.